# Customized thread-local allocator for boost::variant type

Tags: c++, boost-variant, memory-pool

I have implemented a memory pool based on c++ standard allocator interface.

```
template <typename T, size_t Cap = 8>
class SingularAllocator {

  // member declarations ...

  public:

    inline SingularAllocator();                             // Constructor.
    inline ~SingularAllocator();                            // Destructor.

    inline T* allocate(const size_t n=1) ;                  // Allocate an entry of type T.
    inline void deallocate(T*, const size_t n=1);           // Deallocate an entry of type T.

    template <typename... ArgsT>    
    inline void construct(T*, ArgsT&&...);                  // Construct an item.
    inline void destroy(T*);                                // Destroy an item.

  private:

    thread_local Mempool _slot;                                          

    // member implementations ...
}
```

For simplicity, the above snippet shows only the interface. The idea is to use `thread_local` keyword to enable a memory pool for each thread. My question is how can I use this to have each `boost::variant` object created from my pool? For STL like `std::vector`, it's pretty easy as the template argument takes an additional field of allocator. However, I didn't see this in `boost::variant`.

```
boost::variant<int, string, OtherClass> MyStuf; // How to create this variant from my memory pool (per-thread).
```

Comment: Can you not just specify the allocator to the appropriate types in the variant?

Comment: @james boost variant itself will allocate memory